# Can I use Slash (the scripting language) as a scripting engine in my program?

Tags: c++, scripting, slash

My goal would be to use [Slash](http://slash-lang.org/) as a scripting language somehow, much like how you can use Lua in your programs as a scripting engine. The source code for Slash is available (it's written in C), which is why I think this is at least worth experimenting with.

Is it generally supported as a scripting language, and if so, is there any documentation on this? If it's not supported, do you think it's still possible to do? If so, how?

I couldn't find any appropriate material on the web, so I'm asking here. Is it possible? :)

Comment: Welcome to computer science, where the answer to "do you think it's still possible" is almost always _yes_, and when you consider that it's provided as a scripting engine to another program now (a web server), then the answer is actually _of course, yes_. As to "how?" -- most likely the scope of that is beyond the permitted scope of Stack Overflow questions. Read the source, understand your own source, find a way to integrate the two.

Comment: I don't really see an obvious way for interfacing [tag:c++]/[tag:c] function calls with [slash](http://slash-lang.org/), besides interacting via std I/O.

Comment: You're completely right, mah! I'm looking for more "experienced" answers though. People who've worked with it before, or have tried to work with it before. :)

Comment: @AngeloGeels In principle you can integrate literally **any** scripting language/engine into your C++ programs via the right execution calls for it. Or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @g-makulik I'm asking if it's generally a supported thing to integrate it into existing C/C++ programs that are not webservers.

Comment: @AngeloGeels So this completely depends on what you want to achieve, and how you need to call the engine from the application. Appearantly slash is intended to do some text processing on HTTP requests, i.e. you give it a HTTP request and it renders the data for response. So if your C++ API uses it this way, it's fine.

Comment: _'I'm looking for more "experienced" answers though.'_ Make your question a bounty then. But looking on what's available on their [github site](https://github.com/slash-lang/slash) it doesn't seem to be worth it.